# Dell poweredge T310 memory upgrade issue

Tags: memory, upgrade, ecc

I have a Dell PowerEdge T310. 
It's specs state it supports 6 x 4GB RAM.
I wanted to upgrade my ram, from 8GB to 24GB. Since it has two `4GB 1333 registered ecc` sticks I bought four more sticks with the same specs.
When I installed them, I got an error on the servers lcd screen saying: `Memory is configured but not usable`.
My bios version is the latest possible. I have tried with four 4GB sticks, same error.

Answer (score 0):

The PowerEdge T310 server's memory configuration differs by ranking system.

The maximum configuration would be 4x4GB ECC Unbuffered sticks.
Or 
4x8GB Reg ECC sticks, provided they are all quad ranks.
24GB is not a recommended configuration:

http://downloads.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_ser_stor_net/esuprt_poweredge/poweredge-t310_Owner%27s%20Manual_en-us.pdf